# Javascript if / else Statement

Tags: javascript

My Syntax gives errors.  I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("I am ready to play!");
var age = 13;
var age = prompt("What's your age?");
if(var age === 13)
{
   console.log("You are allowed to play but at your own risk.");
}
else
{
   console.log(Play on!");
}
```

Comment: you can't declare a var in an if statement

Comment: @DaveAnderson It's just part of a Codecademy lesson on learning to use if/else statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to declare a variable with `var` once:

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("I am ready to play!");
var age = prompt("What's your age?");
if (age === '13') { // age will be a string
    console.log("You are allowed to play but at your own risk.");
} else {
    console.log("Play on!");
}
```

You get a syntax error because you can't declare a variable inside an `if` statement.

Also, notice that you were missing a `"` in the last `console.log`; this will also cause a syntax error.

You have a couple of logical problems, too. First, `age` will be a string, not an integer, so the `age === 13` will never match. Also, there's no point in initializing `age` to `13` and immediately reassigning it.

Comment: Also, 'age' is going to be a string and the explicit '===' will never match.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //this is another solution
 confirm("I am ready to play!");
 var age = prompt("What's your age?");//input type will be string
 age = parseInt(age);                 //can convert to number by parseInt
 if( age === 13)
 {
alert("You are allowed to play but at your own risk.");
 }
 else
 {
 alert("Play on!");
 }
```